# typedef cannot be used with type modifiers

Tags: c, types, typedef

```
typedef int WORD;
short WORD x =2;
```

Compiler throws an error. I have searched in the internet and books. I read that typedef cannot be used with type modidfers [unsigned, signed, long, short.]

And i found that it can be used in the following way.

```
 typedef short int WORD;
 WORD x =2;
```

Why `typedef` cannot be used with type modifiers?

Comment: Check this: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/83420-typedef-modifiers.html

Comment: There are no "*type **modifiers***" in C. Please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In Deep C, i read that typedef cannot be used with type modidfers [unsigned, signed, long, short.]
>   Why typedef cannot be used with type modifiers?

That's nonsense.

> Compiler throws an error.

Because typedef is not text replacement. You can only use one type per declaration. So `short WORD x` makes as little sense as `double int x`.

Comment: `typedef const CONSTANT; const int x =2;` is it an error?

Comment: @user3801433 Implicit int has been removed from the C language, so yes `typedef const CONSTANT;` should give an error.

Answer (score 4):

typedef is for defining type, you cannot use any qualifier.

```
typedef int WORD;
short WORD x =2; // incorrect
WORD x =2; // correct
```

What you want is more of a preprocessor macro like:

```
#define WORD int
short WORD x = 2; // valid
```

Comment: A good difference btw #define and typedef. But it doesn't says the reason

Comment: @user3801433, reason is simple, typedef is for defining type, not to behave like a macro, accept?

Answer (score 2):

1st: `short`(as well as `long` and `signed`) are (also) "*type specifiers*" as for example `int` and `float` are.

The full list is (C11 Standard 6.7.2/1):

> type-specifier:
>
> ```
>   void
>   char
>   short
>   int
>   long
>   float
>   double
>   signed
>   unsigned
>   _Bool
>   _Complex
> ```
>
> *atomic-type-specifier*
>
> *struct-or-union-specifier*
>
> *enum-specifier*
>
> *typedef-name*

Certain of such are combineable (from the C11 Standard 6.7.2/2):

> At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration,
>   and in the specifier-qualifier list in each struct declaration and type name. Each list of
>   type specifiers shall be one of the following multisets (delimited by commas, when there
>   is more than one multiset per item); the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly
>   intermixed with the other declaration specifiers.
>
> — **void**
>
> — **char**
>
> — **signed char**
>
> — **unsigned char**
>
> — **short, signed short, short int,** or **signed short int**
>
> — **unsigned short,** or **unsigned short int**
>
> — **int, signed,** or **signed int**
>
> — **unsigned,** or **unsigned int**
>
> — **long, signed long, long int,** or **signed long int**
>
> — **unsigned long, or unsigned long int**
>
> — **long long, signed long long, long long int,** or **signed long long int**
>
> — **unsigned long long,** or **unsigned long long int**
>
> — **float**
>
> — **double**
>
> — **long double**
>
> — **_Bool**
>
> — **float _Complex**
>
> — **double _Complex**
>
> — **long double _Complex**
>
> — atomic type specifier
>
> — struct or union specifier
>
> — enum specifier
>
> — typedef name

To answer your question:

> Why typedef cannot be used with type modifiers?

As you can see from the list(s) above the C langauge does not define combining a *typedef name* with any other *type specifier* to be valid.